# Minecraft: Custom Witch Command Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to Create a Witch or a Villager that looks like a Witch that will sell things to a player. I have created several custom villagers already and know most of the coding but I am not sure how to change the appearance of a villager or if there is a way to add properties to a witch that will allow it to offer items like a villager does. Is there a way to do such a thing or am I S.O.L? Here is a Basic Villager and witch command for reference.

/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Profession:0,Offers:{Recipes:[{rewardExp:0b,maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:10b},buyB:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:1b},sell:{id:"minecraft:potion",Damage:8197,Count:10b}}]},Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,CanPickUpLoot:1b,NoAI:1,Silent:1}

/summon witch ~ ~1 ~ {PersistenceRequired:1,CanPickUpLoot:1b,NoAI:1,Silent:1}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible solely with commands. Something you should look into is resource pack modeling. It may allow you to add the witch hat to a villager of preference which you *then* spawn with commands.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked into using custom heads and armor which seems to be the closest I'm gonna get to making a villager that looks like a witch. Thank you for clarifying for me though!